# Call to Socrata database returns invalid syntax

Tags: python, json, socrata

When I try this url in a browser, it returns json  data without a problem:

> https://data.cityofgainesville.org/resource/gvua-xt9q.json?$where=report_date between '2015-01-10' and '2015-12-13'

But when I try to make the same call through Python:

```
response = requests.get('https://data.cityofgainesville.org/resource/gvua-xt9q.json?$where=report_date between '2015-01-10' and '2015-12-13')

data = response.json()

data = json_normalize(data)

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

... it returns a syntax error. Why would it work in a browser but not with a call from Python?

Comment: Can you confirm the syntax? It appears there are mismatched quotations `'` in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a couple of issues. As noted in the comment, looks like you have a mismatched set of quotations.

Second, when the error is corrected, there is another error dealing with the SSL certificate. This is unrelated to the query syntax but something wrong either with `requests` library or the SSL certificate itself.

Nevertheless, it appears that changing to `http://` instead of `https://` will work. So, give this a try:

```py
response = requests.get("http://data.cityofgainesville.org/resource/gvua-xt9q.json?$where=report_date between '2015-01-10' and '2015-12-13'")
```